# Why do I suddenly receive "Error detected while processing function <SNR>30_Highlight_Matching_Pair"?

Tags: original-vim

I suddenly receive `Error detected while processing function <SNR>30_Highlight_Matching_Pair` when I want to write parantheses or when moving over parantheses. I can turn off these error message with

```
:NoMatchParen
```

Unfortunatly, I am unable to reconstruct what I have changed in my environment, possibly in the `vimrc` file. Does someone have an idea where I have to look to turn this behavior off?

Comment: most likely this will go away if you update vim to a recent version

Comment: Are more info on the error printed (like line number)? You might want to add info about OS and Vim version to your question.

Comment: Probably it complained about `invalid argument: 0` and that is correct. The plugin should return `'0'` instead of `0`. This has been fixed in a later runtime file update, so make sure you have the latest matchparen plugin and not an outdated version laying around. See also the related issue https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3225

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt this was exactly it. You might want to turn your comment into an answer so that I can accdept it.

Comment: Okay, thanks, will post an answer later tomorrow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you see, comes from the plugin [matchparen](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/plugin/matchparen.vim), that is distributed with vim and which does highlight the matching parenthesis as you edit them. Internally is uses the `searchpairpos()` function.

Starting with Vim patch [8.1.0112](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0112), Vim will throw an error, if the `skip` argument for the functions `searchpair()` and `searchpairpos()` is not a string argument.

That caused the error message `invalid argument: 0`, because the two plugins `matchparen` and `matchpair` that come with Vim, used a skip expression of `0`.

So a bit later, those two plugins have been changed to make use of a skip expression of `'0'`. So patch [8.1.115](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0115) fixed the matchparen plugin and patch [8.1.143](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.0143) fixed a related problem with the matchit and matchparen plugin, that should keep Vim responsive, even when the pattern is not found.

If you still see the error, even after you have installed a Vim version later than 8.1.143, that means you most likely have an older matchparen plugin laying around and are not using the latest version that comes with Vim. So make so to update the runtime files properly and delete older plugins in case you have them in your local `.vim` path as well.

The related issue in the Vim bug tracker is https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/3225